# Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module uidemo due to: urlRouterProvider is not defined

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm trying to develop routing using UI router, I'm getting the error while debugging.

I'm getting the below error:

```
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module uidemo due to: urlRouterProvider is not defined
```

I'm passing the depencency in JS file as below:

```
var app= angular.module("uidemo",['ui.router']);
```

I've included reference to js file in my HTML file as below.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="libs/angular.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="libs/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/app.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="views/home/homeCtrl.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="views/dashboard/dashboardCtrl.js"></script>
```

What is the reason i'm, getting this error. How it can be resolved.

```
app.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider){ 
    urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/home'); 
    $stateProvider.state('home', { 
        'url':'/home', 
        'templateUrl':"views/home/home-tpls.html", 
        'controller':"homeCtrl as home" 
    }).state('dashboard', { 
        'url':'/dashboard', 
        'templateUrl':"views/dashboard/dashboard-tpls.html", 
        'controller':"dashboardCtrl as db" 
})
```

Comment: could you add your code where you had state configuration?

Comment: app.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider){

urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/home');

$stateProvider

.state('home', {

   'url':'/home',
   'templateUrl':"views/home/home-tpls.html",
   'controller':"homeCtrl as home"

}).state('dashboard', {
    'url':'/dashboard',
    'templateUrl':"views/dashboard/dashboard-tpls.html",
    'controller':"dashboardCtrl as db"

});

Comment: it should be `$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/home'); ` instead of `urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/home');`

Answer (score 0):

The issue with your configuration appears to be with your

```
app.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider){ 
    urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/home');
```

it should be changed to

```
app.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider){ 
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/home');
```

you simply need a $ in front of urlRouterProvider

Comment: @vishwa You can always thank me and help others by accepting this answer if it solved your problem.